# How to make payment to a payment address using Plutus?

Tags: plutus, transaction, payment

In Plutus, `Ledger.Constraints` has the following Constraints

`mustPayToOtherScript`,
`mustPayToPubKey`,
`mustPayToTheScript`,

Is there a similar constraint that can used send funds to a payment address in Daedalus or Yoroi wallets, using `Plutus`?
None of the above there constraints deal with payment addresses the way I understand.

Comment: Should one of the answers be marked as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

To pay to a full address, you can use `mustPayToPubKeyAddress pkh skh v`

This is not using the bech32 format though. You still need to decode the bech32 string into the public key hash (pkh) and the stake key hash (skh).

Answer (score 0):

It's the mustPayToPubKey fn. It takes the **hash** of the public key of the wallet.
From the validator fn:

```
let tx = mustPayToPubKey (ppRecipient pp) $ lovelaceValueOf $ ppLovelace pp
```

where pp is constructed in the off chain code like this (note the use of pubKeyHash fn):

```
payTrace :: Integer -> Integer -> EmulatorTrace ()
payTrace x y = do
    h1 <- activateContractWallet (Wallet 1) payContractOfficialSolution
    s0 <- Emulator.waitNSlots 1
    Extras.logInfo $ "reached slot " ++ show s0
    callEndpoint @"pay" h1 $ PayParams
        { ppRecipient = pubKeyHash $ walletPubKey $ Wallet 2
          , ppLovelace      = x
        }
...
```

This is all from the week04 of the Plutus Pioneer Program iteration 1.